# I keep getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80028018): Old format or invalid type library. error

Tags: vb.net, excel, listview

I try to update the excel sheet rows with their corresponding row colors from the ListView - objLv

objLv = ListView

I added a Reference to System.Drawing.dll - Runtime Version v2.0.50727 - Version 2.0.0.0

The error occurs at 'workbook.Styles.Item(i).Interior.Color...
So it's the 6th line of the code below. I applied some solutions but can't get the problem solved.

```
Dim oldCI = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
'Me.sCloseDoc(strXLSFile)
Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook = Me.fOpenXlsFile(strXLSFile)

For i As Int32 = 0 To objLv.Items.Count - 1
    workbook.Styles.Item(i).Interior.Color = objLv.Items(i).BackColor
Next
workbook.Save()
```

Comment: This is a fairly old KB article that looks suspiciously like it might be applicable to your situation: It involves a bug wherein an appplication setting a locale ID for English on a computer configured for a non-English language. You might take a look at the link here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320369

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194252.aspx) collection is not 0 based.

Try `workbook.Styles.Item(i+1).Interior.Color = objLv.Items(i).BackColor`.

Also, as David mentioned in the comments, you'll need to reset the culture after saving the WorkBook as follows:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CType(oldCI, CultureInfo)
```

Comment: I had to reset the old culture info after setting the color, after the workbook.Save(). This fixed the problem. Please update your answer so I will accept it.

Comment: @ISeeSharp - Updated.